# Way to set "--rm" flag for Ansible Docker module?

Tags: docker, ansible

I am using the [Ansible Docker module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) and trying to run docker with the "[--rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up-rm)" flag set. However, I do not see an option for specifying to use the "--rm" flag or a way to pass in which Docker flags to set on the Ansible Docker Module.

Is there a way to set the "--rm" flag when starting a container with the Ansible Docker module?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Docker module linked by OP is deprecated and @Lexandro's answer is outdated.

This is now supported in the newer module named [docker_container](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_container_module.html#docker-container) as the `auto_remove` feature (added in 2.4)

Answer (score 1):

**deprecated**

--rm only implemented in the docker client itself with combining two functions: run then remove and only works in interactive mode. So you can't run container with -d option or invoke this function via RESTful API. You can use --rm only in case if you call it via docker run --rm ...........

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood how --rm was being used. I actually don't even need it then and it would make no since to have --rm set when starting a container from Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a older docker API version, then you will get

> "msg": "Docker API version is x.xx. Minimum version required is x.xx to set auto_remove option."

Hence may be you can use the

> cleanup: yes

It cleans up the container after the command executes which does the same as --rm.

I had similar issue when I had,

> "msg": "Docker API version is 1.23. Minimum version required is 1.25 to set auto_remove option."